# Can not solve the reference cursor errors in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

PL/SQL reference cursor:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
  c1   cur;
  emp  emp_table%ROWTYPE;
  stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'select * from emp_table';
  CURSOR c2 IS
    SELECT DISTINCT dept_id FROM emp_table;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c2 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('the department no is ' || i.dept_id);
  END LOOP;

  IF i.dept_id IS NULL THEN
    OPEN c1 FOR stmt;
  ELSE
    stmt := stmt || ' where dept_id = i.dept_id';
    OPEN c1 FOR stmt USING i.dept_id;
  END IF;

  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO emp;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(c1.dept_id || ' , ' || c1.emp_name || ' , ' || c1.emp_sal);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c1;

END;
/
```

errors I got are

```
**ORA-06550: line 11, column 4:                           
PLS-00201: identifier 'I.DEPT_ID' must be declared                 
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:                 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored                      
ORA-06550: line 19, column 25:                     
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'C1'                   
ORA-06550: line 19, column 1:                          
PL/SQL: Statement ignored                       
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"                    
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.                           
*Action:**
```

I tried running the above code and getting errors.
Please help me to solve this error. Please tell me the good links to study PL/SQL.

Comment: http://plsql-tutorial.com/ you can try this link.

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt := stmt || ' where dept_id = i.dept_id';
```

should be

```
stmt := stmt || ' where dept_id = :1';
```

Comment: But its a bad design, you can use parameterised cursor or can merge both cursors into one.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from error above, you try to use `i.dept_id` outside the loop where it is declared.

It should be this one:

```
FOR i IN c2 LOOP          
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the department no is ' || i.dept_id);              
    IF i.dept_id IS NULL THEN 
        OPEN c1 FOR stmt;  
    ELSE   
        stmt := stmt || ' where dept_id = :p1';              
        OPEN c1 FOR stmt USING i.dept_id;           
    END IF;                  
    LOOP                     
        FETCH c1 INTO emp;          
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;      
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c1.dept_id||' , '||c1.emp_name||' , '||c1.emp_sal);          
    END LOOP;  
    CLOSE c1;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite answering your question you can make your code a bit shorter.
You have two queries that you can combine into one.

Query 1 (if i.dept_id is null)

```
select * 
from emp_table;
```

Query 2 (if i.dept_id is not null)

```
select * 
from emp_table 
where dept_id=i.dept_id;
```

You can easily create one query for both cases:

```
select * 
   from emp_table 
   where (i.dept_id is null or dept_id=i.dept_id);
```